# Spring boot async controller

Tags: java, ajax, spring

I have this post method:

```
 @PostMapping("/upload")
        public String singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
                throws IOException {
    ExecutorService service= Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            Future<String> future=service.submit(new Callable<String>() {
                @Override
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    //parse file
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    return "done";
                }
            });
    String result=future.get();
     service.shutdown();
    return "redirect:uploadState";
    }
```

I want to redirect to uploadState while executor parse my file and uploadState have long polling ajax to notify if parsing is done or not.Can help me with some hints.

Answer (score 2):

Here `future.get()` is blocker.

You can use Java 8 CompletableFuture :

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    try{
   Thread.sleep(5000);
   return "done";
 }catch(Exception ex){}
}).thenApply((res->)->{
  return res;
});
```

It will not block your control.